# linux kernel undefined reference to '__compat_exports_start'

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linker-errors, undefined-reference, gcc5.2

The same situation like in the last question. An android kernel (3.4.0), that I try to compile with gcc 5.2 (Linaro toolchain).

```
arch/arm/mach-msm/built-in.o:memory.c:function check_for_compat: error:    undefined reference to '__compat_exports_start'
arch/arm/mach-msm/built-in.o:memory.c:function check_for_compat: error: undefined reference to '__compat_exports_end'
```

Here are some relevant files from the source for solving the problem:https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzvG7t0B9TTDTk5MNlBEcVgxUVk&usp=sharing

Comment: Which kernel version you trying to compile? BTW "linux-kernel" tag explicitely talks about needing of kernel version.

Comment: Hmm, it looks strange: there is no `arch/arm/mach-msm/memory.c` file in the [android's repo](https://github.com/android/kernel_common/tree/android-3.4/arch/arm/mach-msm).

Comment: @DavidMüller Can you provide us with link to your kernel sources? If yes, please tell us also which `defconfig` file you are using for building, as well.